# Copy Android Studio plugins to offline network

Tags: android, gradle

I have a gradle project which I've transferred to a network that has no internet access.  To resolve all of my dependencies, I've grabbed the files in `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1` and pushed them to my network's Artifactory.

However, when I run `./gradlew build`, I get the error

```
* What went wrong
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.2.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.2.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    my-repo(https://my.artifactory/my-repo/gradle)
```

In `my-repo`, I have the following:

```
gradle/
  com.android.application/
    com.android.application.gradle.plugin/
      8.2.1/
        <some hash>/
          com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.2.1.pom
```

How can I get gradle to find the plugin?

Comment: Have you tried TK run Gradle with `--debug` argument, may be you see then which URLs it accesses. Alternatively check the access log if your repo.

Comment: It's pulling from [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.2.2).  However, that only contains the POM file which I already have in Artifactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do already mirror dependencies into your Artifactory, but Gradle needs to be explicitly told to look in your Artifactory for plugins.
That should be possible by adding a [`pluginManagement` block](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management) in your [`settings.gradle`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html) file:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://my.artifactory/my-repo/gradle'
        }
        gradlePluginPortal() // Optional: If you still want to resolve from Gradle Plugin Portal when online
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.namespace == 'com.android.application') {
                useModule("com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For Kotlin DSL ([`settings.gradle.kts`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html)), see [this example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:plugins_resolution_strategy):

Verify that the artifact in your Artifactory is correctly structured and that all necessary metadata, including `.pom` files and any `.jar` or `.aar` files, are present. Gradle relies on this metadata to resolve dependencies.

For Kotlin DSL ([`settings.gradle.kts`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html)), see [this example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:plugins_resolution_strategy).

Verify that the artifact in your Artifactory is correctly structured and that all necessary metadata, including `.pom` files and any `.jar` or `.aar` files, are present. Gradle relies on this metadata to resolve dependencies.

When running your build, you can force Gradle to resolve dependencies from the local cache or your configured repositories without attempting to reach out to the internet by using the `--offline` flag:

```bash
./gradlew build --offline
```

---

> Interestingly, when I run with `--scan`, it gives me a different error. That is, it now cannot find `com.gradle.enterprise` (which isn't in Artifactory).

The error related to `com.gradle.enterprise` not being found in Artifactory suggests that there might be additional plugins or dependencies not mirrored in your Artifactory. That plugin (the [`com.gradle.enterprise`](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.gradle.enterprise) one) is often used for Gradle Enterprise or build scans, which helps in diagnosing build issues but also needs to be available in your repository if your build configuration requires it. You might need to add this plugin to your Artifactory or adjust your build configuration to not require it for offline builds.
If `com.gradle.enterprise` is essential for your build, apply a similar `pluginManagement` strategy to resolve this plugin from your Artifactory, similar to how you have done for `com.android.application`.
If the `com.gradle.enterprise` plugin is not relevant for your offline builds, consider conditionally applying this plugin based on whether an internet connection is available or not. That can be achieved with logic in your `build.gradle` or `settings.gradle` files to check for connectivity before applying the plugin.

> Is my directory structure correct? Or should it be `com.android/application`?

The convention for storing artifacts in Maven repositories (which Artifactory emulates) typically uses forward slashes (`/`) to separate the group ID, artifact ID, and version in the path. However, [Gradle's plugin management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html) system uses a slightly different notation for plugins, which is why you specify plugins with IDs like `com.android.application` in your build script, but the actual artifact might be stored in a path structured like `com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.2.1/`. It is important to make sure your Artifactory mirrors the structure expected by Gradle, which generally means translating plugin IDs into a Maven-compatible path structure.

---

> So, I listed the directory structure in my original post? Is that what Gradle expects?

The directory structure you have listed for the plugin in your Artifactory is:

```
gradle/
  com.android.application/
    com.android.application.gradle.plugin/
      8.2.1/
        <some hash>/
          com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.2.1.pom
```

It does not align with the conventional Maven repository layout that Gradle expects when resolving plugins and dependencies.

Gradle, when resolving plugins, expects a Maven-like structure where the path to a particular artifact is constructed from its group ID, artifact ID, and version. The structure you have described seems to be a direct transfer of the Gradle cache structure, which is different.

For a Gradle plugin, the expected Maven repository layout would typically look something like this:

```
com/android/application/<version>/com.android.application-<version>.jar
```

or, for the Gradle plugin marker artifact, which Gradle uses to map plugin IDs to actual artifacts:

```
com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/<version>/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-<version>.pom
```

The `.pom` file should define the dependency on the actual plugin JAR artifact, which would then be stored in a path similar to the first example.

Based on the error message and your description, it seems like Gradle is unable to resolve the plugin because it is looking for a marker artifact that follows this structure, but cannot find it in the specified repository. The structure within your Artifactory should instead reflect the Maven layout, as Gradle plugins are published in a manner compatible with Maven repositories.

You might need to reorganize the plugin artifacts in your Artifactory to match the Maven structure. For the `com.android.application` plugin version `8.2.1`, the structure in Artifactory should look more like this:

```
com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.2.1/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.2.1.pom
```

And make sure the `.pom` file points to the correct JAR file, which should also be available in your Artifactory under the plugin's group and artifact ID path. That might involve manually uploading the plugin JAR and its `.pom` file to Artifactory in the correct locations, if you have not done so already.

Remember, the actual plugin's JAR file should also be present in the repository and correctly referenced by the `.pom` file, which may require adding another entry under `com/android/application/` for the plugin's JAR artifact, following the Maven convention.

Comment: No good.  Same error.

Comment: Interestingly, when I run with `--scan`, it gives me a different error.  That is, it now cannot find com.gradle.enterprise (which isn't in Artifactory).

Comment: Is my directory structure correct?  Or should it be `com.android/application`?

Comment: So, I listed the directory structure in my original post?  Is that what Gradle expects?